# Creating a box with SceneKit and ARKit

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I am trying to create a primitive with SceneKit and ARKit. For whatever reason, it is not working.

```
let box = SCNBox(width: 0.1, height: 0.1, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0)

    let node = SCNNode(geometry: box)

    node.position = SCNVector3(0,0,0)

    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```

Do I need to take in the camera coordinates as well?

Answer (score 7):

Your code looks good and it should work. I have tried it as the below code: after creating a new app with ARKit template, I have replaced the function viewDidLoad.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set the view's delegate
    sceneView.delegate = self

    let box = SCNBox(width: 0.1, height: 0.1, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0)
    let node = SCNNode(geometry: box)
    node.position = SCNVector3(0,0,0)
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
}
```

It creates a box at the original point (0, 0, 0). Unfortunately your device is inside the box thus you cannot see that box straightly. To see the box, move your device far aways a bit.

The attached image is the box after moving my device:

[image]

If you want to see it immediately, move the box to front a bit, add colour and make the first material be double side (to see it even in or out side):

```
    let box = SCNBox(width: 0.1, height: 0.1, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0)
    box.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
    box.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
    let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: box)
    boxNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -1)
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should get the location tapped and use the world coordinates to place the cube properly. I'm not sure (0,0,0) is a normal location for ARKit. You can try something like this:
Put this in your viewDidLoad:

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTapFrom))
tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
self.sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

Then add this method:

```
@objc func handleTapFrom(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let tapPoint = recognizer.location(in: self.sceneView)
    let result = self.sceneView.hitTest(tapPoint, types: ARHitTestResult.ResultType.existingPlaneUsingExtent)

    if result.count == 0 {
        return
    }

    let hitResult = result.first

    let box = SCNBox(width: 0.1, height: 0.1, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0)

    let node = SCNNode(geometry: box)
    node.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType.static, shape: nil)
    node.position = SCNVector3Make(hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.x, hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.y, hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.z)

    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
}
```

Then when you tap on a plane surface detected, it will add a box on the plane where you tapped.

Comment: I got a build error and changed this part. It didn't work so I changed it to this. 

'node.position = SCNVector3Make((hitResult?.worldTransform.columns.3.x)!, (hitResult?.worldTransform.columns.3.y)!, (hitResult?.worldTransform.columns.3.z)!)'

Comment: It didn't add a cube. I was trying something simple to just add a cube to the scene in AR. I am not sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: 0,0,0 is a perfectly valid location in ARKit. The origin on the world coordinate system is

Comment: (accidental send button too soon) ...is where your device was when you started the ARSession. If you haven’t moved since then, your device is still inside a 10cm cube, which you can’t see because the inside faces aren’t rendered. If you pull back a bit, you should see the cube floating there, though. The world origin is probably not a *useful* place to put things, though. The hit-test based placement shown in this answer is just one way (of many possible) to get content at a useful position.